# Ubuntu 22.04 unable to shutdown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, boot

I am having an issue, I can't shutdown my ubuntu laptop. Looks like it just gets stuck. I looked in multiple forums without luck and I thought maybe I could find help.

To be able to see the log I have disabled the splash screen in the grub config and this is what I see:

[image]

> kvm: exiting hadware virtualization

I tried searching for that message on google but I couldn't solve the problem. I don't really understand what it means. In case this helps diagnosing the issue I also want to include some more info in this question. See below.

```
$lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             499712  0
kvm                  1347584  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
```

My OS version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

My hardware spec:
[image]

Comment: please share your system log too `journalctl`